# PostGIS: snap latitude/longitude input to nearest OSM road point

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I need a function to return the nearest OSM road point for any latitude/longitude. i.e. users input a latitude/longitude and postgis finds and uses the point on a road that is the nearest to it. Particularly, this needs to be fast.

Here's an extract of my current - slow - solution:

```
select "geom" 
from (select (ST_DumpPoints(geom_vertex)).geom 
  from "roads_2po_v") as "vertex" 
    order by ST_Distance(geom, 
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('103.84743100000003','1.2987212'), 4326)) 
 limit '1')
```

Unfortunately this `order by ST_Distance... limit 1` slows down the entire query about 500x. What would be an improved way to snap to nearest road point in PostGIS using OSM data?

roads_2po_y is a table constructed using osm2po like so:

```
java -jar osm2po-core-4.8.8-signed.jar prefix=roads cmd=c roads/data.pbf
```

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE roads_2po_v (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  clazz integer,
  osm_id bigint,
  osm_name character varying,
  ref_count integer,
  restrictions character varying
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'roads_2po_v', 'geom_vertex', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

So I'd like to know:

1. Best/most efficient way to get OSM road points into PostGIS (note: it's for a particular region, not the world)
2. Efficient query for finding nearest road point when given a latitude and longitude

Any other questions/answers I've found on the site are wrapped in custom requirements. I'm seeking a generic function that returns nearest OSM road point for any given latitude/longitude.

Comment: use ST_ClosestPoint http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

Comment: g2 of ST_ClosestPoint would be my input lat/long as a geom point, but not sure how I would construct g1?

Comment: There is also ST_Line_Locate_Point http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html

Comment: For g1 perhaps you could use ST_Collect to gather all line segments where the 'highway' attribute is not null (or is within a set of values that you're interested in) into a single geometry.  http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Comment: This query returns the right answer:
select 
 ST_X(ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom_vertex, point.geom)),
 ST_Y(ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom_vertex, point.geom)),
 ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_ClosestPoint(ST_Transform(r.geom_vertex, 4326), point.geom), point.geom)
from roads_2po_v r,
 (select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('103.8319629999999','1.304011'), 4326) as geom) point
order by 3 asc
limit 1

but not sure if it's efficient or not.

Comment: Do you have a spatial index?

Comment: @raphael I haven't added any spatial index yet. Would any particular type assist with the above code snippet I posted?

Comment: @rgareth4 It will speed up your nearest neighbour search by limiting the number of distance comparisons made in the `ORDER BY` clause